# unrecognized command line option "-fvar-tracking-assignments-toggle" error in cc1plus

Tags: compiler-construction, g++

During compilation I get following error:

```
cc1plus: error: unrecognized command line option "-fvar-tracking-assignments-toggle"
```

If `cc1plus` ran, then there isn't a `g++` installation problem. Right?
I don't know how to interpret this error or how to fix it.

Comment: Can you include more specifics about what you are running?  Specific commands that you are invoking would be helpful.

Comment: Absolutely! I'm running and offline base caller.http://support.illumina.com/sequencing/sequencing_software/offline_basecaller_olb.ilmn. When I run 'make install' it gives that error.

Comment: Could it be that you're using an old version of the GNU compiler collection, which does not support this feature?